# Show dialogs with async task in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I want to show dialog when async task start downloading content from web in onPreExecute method,and delete the dialog when downloading has done in onPostExecute method,

```
    public class ListNumbers extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lView;
    private NumberAdapter mNumAdapt;
    public List<String> numes;
    private ArrayList<Phonesnum> numbersList;

    public AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> mTask;
    private String json_string;

    private String url="the url where to download content";

    public class DownloadLink extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Log.i("URL",strings[0]);

            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder("");

            URL ur;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try{
                ur = new URL(strings[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)ur.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1){
                    char current = (char)data;

                    res.append(current);

                    data = reader.read();
                }

                return res.toString();

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return  "failed";
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            h.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                            getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);

                    // create the popup window
                    int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                    int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, false);

                    // show the popup window
                    // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window tolken
                    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            try {
                //JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);

                //String weatherInfo = jObject.getString("number");


                //Log.i("number",weatherInfo);

                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(s);

                for (int i =0;i < arr.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jpart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                    String number = jpart.getString("number");
                    //numes.add(number);

                    String prc = jpart.getString("price");

                    numbersList.add(new Phonesnum(number,prc));
                }

                //ArrayAdapter<String> arad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListNumbers.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,numes);
                NumberAdapter nmAdapter = new NumberAdapter(ListNumbers.this,numbersList);
                lView.setAdapter(nmAdapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_numbers);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.title_bar);

        numes = new ArrayList<>();
        numbersList = new ArrayList<>();

        lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_ve);

        if (numes.size() == 0){

        }
        new Thread(new Getnumbers()).start();
    }

    class Getnumbers implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String result = null;
            DownloadLink task = new DownloadLink();
            try {

                result = task.execute(url).get();
                Log.i("result",result);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here i have put a popup window depending on previous question here in the website..but i can't control when to show or hide the popup,cause the popup created in handler and i can't access it from onPostExecute method....i have tried and created progress bar with inflater before in global section then 
i tried to access it from the GetNumber thread but it showed me error cause you must create the progess bar and inflate the layout from the main thread

Comment: please format your question properly

Comment: excuse me,is there any thing wrong?

Comment: Hi, it wasn't formatted well before. You can still remove unnecessary spaces in the code.Thanks!

Comment: Try to pass a weak reference of the Activity into the AsyncTask. Then you can call. activity.runOnUiThread()